# On the derivation of path integral and completeness identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, path-integral

I know that the unitary propagator between two points $x_{i}, x_{f}$ at instants $t_i, t_f$ is given by

$$K(t_i, t_f, x_i, x_f) = \langle x_i, t_i| x_f, t_f\rangle = \langle x_f|e^{i\frac{(t_f-t_i)}{\hbar}H}|x_i\rangle$$

Time slicing into $n$ intervals $\delta t = \frac{(t_f-t_i)}{n}$ gives us

$$\langle x_i, t_i| x_f, t_f\rangle = \langle x_f|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}\cdots e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}|x_i\rangle$$

From the completeness identity,

$$\int |x_n\rangle\langle x_n|dx_n = \mathbb{I}\rightarrow \int |x_n\rangle\langle x_n|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}dx_n  = e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}$$

$$\prod^{n}_{j = 1}\biggr(\int |x_j\rangle\langle x_j|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}dx_j\biggr) = \int |x_n\rangle\langle x_j|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}|x_{j-1}\rangle\cdots \langle x_2|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}|x_{1}\rangle \langle x_1|dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{n} $$

Position basis satisfies $\langle x_k|x_j\rangle = \delta(k-j)$, and so if $x_1 = x_i$ and $x_n = x_f$,

$$\begin{align}K(t_i, t_f, x_i, x_f) &= \langle x_f|\prod^{n}_{j = 1}\biggr(\int |x_j\rangle\langle x_j|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}dx_j\biggr)|x_i\rangle\\ &= \int \langle x_j|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}|x_{j-1}\rangle\cdots \langle x_2|e^{i\frac{\delta t}{\hbar}H}|x_{1}\rangle dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{n}\end{align}$$

Derivation of path integral, of course, takes more work. However, is this the idea behind how we make use of completeness identity?

Comment: Yes. However, if you work in this position space path integral, then the normalisation factors would blow up. If you want to make even more sense out of that, you should insert momentum completeness identities and then no weirdness will appear. That is, the phase space path integral is slightly more sensible than the position space path integral.